# React how to wait for component/page to render to call function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to modify the data-scroll attribute of the first div I return here. Problem seems to be a race hazard - active is null because the dom hasn't loaded yet. How do I deal with this? async/await? I'm not querying something and I won't get a response. How do I wait until the Header is rendered?

this generates TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataset' of null:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import * as ROUTES from '../constants/routes';

export default function Header() {
  const active = document.getElementById('navbar');

  const debounce = (fn) => {
    let frame;
    return (...params) => {
      if (frame) {
        cancelAnimationFrame(frame);
      }
      frame = requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        fn(...params);
      });
    };
  };
  const storeScroll = () => {
    if (window.scrollY > 80) {
      active.dataset.scroll = window.scrollY;
    }
    if (window.scrollY <= 80) {
      active.dataset.scroll = 0;
    }
  };

  // Listen for new scroll events
  document.addEventListener('scroll', debounce(storeScroll), { passive: true });

  // Update scroll position for first time
  storeScroll();
  return (
    <div id="navbar" data-scroll="0">
      <header className="fixed flex top-0 scroll:bg-blue-500 bg-transparent items-center justify-center p-5 w-full">
        <div className="container mx-auto max-w-screen-lg h-full">
          <div className="flex justify-between h-full">
            <div className="text-black text-center flex items-center align-items cursor-pointer">
              <h1 className="flex justify-center w-full">
                <Link to={ROUTES.TEST} className="font-bold text-lg" aria-label="home">
                  HOME
                </Link>
              </h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not a good practice to target a underlying DOM in react directly . We can use the `ref` to do that.

Also you are adding an `eventListener` which does not get removed correctly when the component unmounts . so to make sure you have the element when the rendering is complete you can make use of the `useEffect` hook which guarantees that it is ran after the DOM is painted.

So you need to have your eventListener code to be move in the useEffect hook . Here is the updated code using `Ref` and `useEffect` .

```
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import * as ROUTES from '../constants/routes';
import {useRef, useEffect} from 'react';

export default function Header() {
  const navbarRef = useRef();

  const debounce = (fn) => {
    let frame;
    return (...params) => {
      if (frame) {
        cancelAnimationFrame(frame);
      }
      frame = requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        fn(...params);
      });
    };
  };

  const storeScroll = () => {
    if (window.scrollY > 80) {
      navbarRef.current.dataset.scroll = window.scrollY;
    }
    if (window.scrollY <= 80) {
      navbarRef.current.dataset.scroll = 0;
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // Update scroll position for first time
    storeScroll();
    
    // attact the event listener
    window.addEventListener('scroll', debounce(storeScroll), {passive: true});
    
    // remove the event listener when the component is unmounted
    return () =>
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', debounce(storeScroll), {
        passive: true,
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id="navbar" ref={navbarRef} data-scroll="0">
      <header className="fixed flex top-0 scroll:bg-blue-500 bg-transparent items-center justify-center p-5 w-full">
        <div className="container mx-auto max-w-screen-lg h-full">
          <div className="flex justify-between h-full">
            <div className="text-black text-center flex items-center align-items cursor-pointer">
              <h1 className="flex justify-center w-full">
                <Link
                  to={ROUTES.TEST}
                  className="font-bold text-lg"
                  aria-label="home"
                >
                  HOME
                </Link>
              </h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useEffect` hook for that:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'; 

useEffect(()=>{
  // what should happen after the initial render
  const active = document.getElementById('navbar');
  active.setAttribute("data-scroll", <your_value>)
},[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a `ref` to "catch" the DOM element.

```js
const debounce = (fn) => {
  let frame;
  return (...params) => {
    if (frame) {
      cancelAnimationFrame(frame);
    }
    frame = requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      fn(...params);
    });
  };
};

const storeScroll = (element) => () => {
  if (window.scrollY > 80) {
    active.dataset.scroll = window.scrollY;
  }
  if (window.scrollY <= 80) {
    active.dataset.scroll = 0;
  }
};

export default function Header() {
  const addScrollListener = (element) => {
    if (!element) { 
      return null;
    }

    document.addEventListener('scroll', debounce(storeScroll(element)), { passive: true });
    storeScroll(element);
  }

  return (
    <div id="navbar" data-scroll="0" ref={addScrollListener}>
      ...
    </div>
  );
}
```

Even though you *can* use `document.getElementById`, it is discouraged in React, and the idiomatic way to get references to DOM elements is through refs.

Pulling the functions out of the component is not strictly necessary, just a practice I'd recommend.

See [Refs and the DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

Answer (score 0):

1. bind the events inside the **useEffect** only

```
useEffect(() => {
  document.addEventListener('scroll', debounce(storeScroll), { passive: true });
}, []);
```

2. same way you can access navbar in **useEffect**

   ```
    useEffect(() => {
        const active = document.getElementById('navbar');
    }, [])
   ```